# Momentum and Inertia in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, game-physics

So, when my i let go off my keys the controller stops like it hits a wall, i tried changing that but all that changed is that now it gets flung into outer space every time i press a key:

```
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    Vector3 newMovement = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
    momentum = new Vector3(characterController.velocity.x, 0, characterController.velocity.z);
    newMovement.y = 0;
 if (!newMovement.normalized.Equals(momentum.normalized))
        {
            
            Debug.Log("new" + newMovement.normalized);
            Debug.Log(momentum.normalized);

            momentum = (momentum.magnitude - 2f) > 0 ? momentum.normalized * (momentum.magnitude - 2f) : Vector3.zero;
            

            if (newMovement.x == momentum.x)
                momentum.x = 0;



            if (newMovement.z == momentum.z)
                momentum.z = 0;



            
        }
        else
            momentum = Vector3.zero;
        characterController.Move((newMovement * speed + velocity + momentum) * Time.deltaTime);
```

Also for some reason even though sometimes both vectors are equal they pass through the if statement(i tried using !=)(both vectors are logged on the first 2 lines of the if statement)

[image]

Comment: Well it stopped like a wall because you set movement to zero. Normally you would add momentum to the existing like thrusters. When there is value to x or z. If there is none then it would just keep the momentum. And you use thrusters to slow (as you are talking of space) you could let to zero if you wanted it to come to a halt naturally

Comment: You are viewing only 2 decimal places of those vectors' components.  If you look at the actual values of those components, you will see they are not the same.

Comment: @hijinxbassist well how can i round their values?

Comment: @BugFinder my initial issue was that it stops like a wall, that's normal unity, with character controllers you don't get physics. So i tried adding momentum but all that happened is that my character started flying into space when i press any key.

Comment: Use `Vector3.SmoothDamp` or `Vector3.Lerp`

Answer (score 0):

Use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html, it will gradually slow the movement to zero, depending on the value of `smoothTime`:

```
public float smoothTime = 0.3F;
private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
private Vector3 newMovement;

void Update()
{
    newMovement = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPosition, ref velocity, smoothTime);
}
```

Comment: `smoothTime = Mathf.Abs(characterController.velocity.x) * 1.25f;
            finalPos =  transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(transform.position.x + (5), transform.position.y, transform.position.z));
            transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(
                    transform.position,
                    finalPos,
                    ref velocity,
                    0.3f
                    );
`
i tried that but now i just get dragged into infinity

Comment: Don't use `TransformPoint`, it translates from local to world space which is completely inappropriate, just use a basic `Vector3`. Don't use a dynamic variable for `smoothTime` like `characterController.velocity.x` just use a simple float like `1.25f`.